# How to set frontpage content on Drupal site with MAMP?

Tags: reactjs, drupal, mamp, drush

I have an existing site that uses Drupal. I am using MAMP and the document root points to the web folder where the page to be displayed is located. When I go to "my website" from the MAMP web start page I get a generic Drupal page that says no front page content has been created but I am expecting the my site to be served. How do I get my site to display instead of this message?

Answer (score 1):

"no front page content has been created" is the standard drupal front page message.

The standard Drupal front page automatically displays any nodes that have been "promoted to the front page", but since on a new drupal install, no nodes have been created (and promoted to the front page), you will get that message.
**EDIT:** Actually, I think in D8, the front page is a view.

There are a multitude of different ways to set the content on the front page, depending on your needs.
There is even a [module called "front page" specifically](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) for it.

What I have often done, is create a "basic page" node, and then set the front page to be this node in the theme settings. As this node is usually the first thing I create, it will be "node/1", which is what I enter into the front page setting.

I think the automatic displaying of "promoted to front page" nodes on the front page is a remnant from the old days when Drupal was often used as a blogging platform